# Why is while not not working?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

AIM: To find files with a word count less than 1000 and move them another folder. Loop until all under 1k files are moved.

STATUS: It will only move one file, then error with "Unable to move file as it doesn't exist. For some reason $INPUT_SMALL doesn't seem to update with the new file name."

What am I doing wrong?

Current Script:

> Check for input files already under 1k and move to Split folder

```
INPUT_SMALL=$( ls -S /folder1/ | grep -i reply | tail -1  )

INPUT_COUNT=$( cat /folder1/$INPUT_SMALL 2>/dev/null | wc -l  )

function moveSmallInput() {

    while  [[ $INPUT_SMALL != ""  ]] && [[ $INPUT_COUNT -le 1003  ]]
    do
        echo "Files smaller than 1k have been found in input folder, these will be moved to the split folder to be processed."
        mv /folder1/$INPUT_SMALL /folder2/
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks William, That was just a stackoverflow typo Not in the script

Comment: `wc -l < /folder/$INPUT_SMALL` is better

Comment: `wc -c < /folder/$INPUT_SMALL` will show the character count of the file, not the line count. Use `wc -w < file` for WORD Count per the first sentence in your question. Good luck to all.

Comment: Sorry, it was Line count I was after. Not word count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for files that has the word reply somewhere in the path. My solution is:

```
wc -w $(find /folder1 -type f -path '*reply*') | \
    while read wordcount filename
    do
        if [[ $wordcount -lt 1003 ]]
        then
            printf "%4d %s\n" $wordcount $filename
            #mv "$filename" /folder2
        fi
    done
```

Run the script once, if the output looks correct, then uncomment the `mv` command and run it for real this time.

#### Update

The above solution has trouble with files with embedded spaces. The problem occurs when the `find` command hands its output to the `wc` command. After a little bit of thinking, here is my revised soltuion:

```
find /folder1 -type f -path '*reply*' | \
    while read filename
    do
        set $(wc -w "$filename") # $1= word count, $2 = filename
        wordcount=$1
        if [[ $wordcount -lt 1003 ]]
        then
            printf "%4d %s\n" $wordcount $filename
            #mv "$filename" /folder2
        fi
    done
```

Comment: is this save if the filenames contain spaces?

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat shorter version

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./folder1 -type f | while read f 
do
    (( $(wc -w "$f" | awk '{print $1}' ) < 1000 )) && cp "$f" folder2
done
```

I left `cp` instead of `mv` for safery reasons. Change to `mv` after validating

I you also want to filter with `reply` use @Hai's version of the `find` command

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `INPUT_SMALL` and `INPUT_COUNT` are not functions, they're just values you assigned once.  You either need to move them inside your `while` loop or turn them into functions and evaluate them each time (rather than just expanding the variable values, as you are now).

Comment: Ok, I will give that one a try. Thanks Ben